# the table is not registered or you do not have access to it (documentum)

Tags: dql, documentum

I am using documentum data storage and and I have an object table called dm_user . I can fetch data from the table by running a DQL query like :

```
select * from dm_user where user_name = 'dkfloza'
```

However when I run a query to update my table such as :

```
update dm_user set user_email = 'dkfloza@gmail.com' where user_name ='dkfloza'
```

I recieve an error saying that :

> the table is not registered or you do not have access to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax for DQL update in this case is:

```
UPDATE dm_user OBJECT
SET user_email = 'dkfloza@gmail.com'
WHERE user_name = 'dkfloza'
```

If you do not provide `OBJECT`, the parser thinks that you are trying to update a registered table instead of an object.

Please note: DQL does not deal with tables directly (apart from registered tables, which is an exception to this rule). Instead, it deals with objects. Objects consist of several tables that are joined together automatically by the Documentum Content Server. Therefore it is incorrect to state that you have a *row in a table* called dm_user. Instead, you should say that you have an *object of type* dm_user.

Comment: how about insertion of a new row ? 
insert into dm_user object (user_name) values('testing'); 
it gives me syntax error .  why ?

Comment: `CREATE dm_user OBJECT SET attr1 = 'val1', SET attr2 = 'val2'` (notice the comma between each `SET` statement)

Comment: how about removing a row? :))